# Scala - How to Return this Kind of RDD type

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I try to make method that return RDD refer to [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html), but failed because the return need parameter. According to API (Java), Here's my code:

```
def HBaseToRDD(_HBaseConfiguration:HBaseConfiguration, _sc:SparkContext) : RDD[(K, V)] = 
{
val HBaseRDD = _sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(_HBaseConfiguration, classOf[TableInputFormat],
            classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
            classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
}
```

Any Idea to solve this ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is `K` and `V`? I don't see them in your method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As Yuval Itzchakov already mentioned the information about `K` and `V` is missing, furthermore I observe following:

1. You are missing return value in your method
2. even if you would return your `val HBaseRDD` the code would still not compile because expected return value is of type `RDD[(K, V)]` but `val HBaseRDD` is of type `RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result)]`

With this and couple of assumptions in mind, a working code sample could look like this:

```
def HBaseToRDD[K, V](_HBaseConfiguration:HBaseConfiguration, _sc:SparkContext) : RDD[(K, V)] =
{
  def toK(key: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable): K = {
    // here you convert key to K
  }

  def toV(row: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result): V = {
    // here you convert row to V
  }

  // no need to assign to variable, the result of map will be returned by scala
  _sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(_HBaseConfiguration, classOf[TableInputFormat],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]).map { case (key, row) =>
    toK(key) -> toV(row) // return tuple of type (K, V)
  }
}
```